# What is the difference between the ShowSuperHidden and SuperHidden registry values?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Under the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

...there are two well-documented values that pertain to the showing of hidden files and folders in Windows Explorer.

The `Hidden` key shows hidden files when true, and hides them when false.

The `ShowSuperHidden` key is generally acknowledged as its equivalent for "super hidden" (i.e. protected/system) files; it shows super-hidden files when true, and hides them when false.

That said, where does the `SuperHidden` value come in? Its name suggests it would be the natural analogue to the `Hidden` key, but documentation on it and what it does is non-existent as far as I've been able to tell.

**What is the purpose of the `SuperHidden` value, and how does it differ from `ShowSuperHidden`?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ShowSuperHidden`, [as we discovered](https://superuser.com/a/1240351/380318), controls whether super-hidden (Hidden + System) files are displayed. As far as I can tell, `SuperHidden` controls nothing and its existence is probably a programming error.

Using [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), I observed reads from and writes to these Registry values. The only interaction with `SuperHidden` was a write when the user opened the View tab of the Folder Options dialog. It received a 1 if super-hidden files are displayed, 0 otherwise. It was never read, even when I terminated and restarted Explorer.

Procmon provides the stack that led to a monitored operation (double-click an event and consult the Stack tab), so I examined the DLL files involved using [IDA v5.0](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml). The only relevant one with a mention of `SuperHidden` was `shell32.dll`. The `CachedShellState::SaveAdvancedSettings` function issues a Registry write to that value and others in that key, committing the current view settings.

[image: writing SuperHidden in SaveAdvancedSettings]

Explorer apparently calls that function before showing the View tab. That's probably done to make sure the Registry is consistent with the current in-memory settings before loading the current state of the View options, though I admit I'm not 100% certain on the reasoning. Anyway, the corresponding `shell32.dll` function `CachedShellState::_GetAdvancedSettings` issues a read from the correct value, `ShowSuperHidden`.

[image: reading ShowSuperHidden in _GetAdvancedSettings]

These disassembly listings are from the Windows 7 version of that DLL. In Windows 10, `SuperHidden` does not exist in the Registry, and `CachedShellState::SaveAdvancedSettings` writes to `ShowSuperHidden`.

[image: Windows 10 writes to ShowSuperHidden in SaveAdvancedSettings]

Therefore, I conclude that when programming the version of that function that comes with Windows 7, a developer mistakenly omitted the `Show` in `ShowSuperHidden`, but the error was corrected along the way to Windows 10.

For the curious, the Folder Options dialog isn't broken by this error because it consults the `ValueName` entry under each setting key here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder
```

Working out the significance of the other parts of that branch is left as a (fun!) exercise to the reader.

Comment: How did you find it is **shell32.dll**? Process Monitor shows **explorer.exe** changes this registry?

Comment: @Biswa Right, `explorer.exe` is the *process* responsible for the change, but it is code inside `shell32.dll` (which Explorer loads) that makes the call. To see DLLs involved, double-click an event and switch to the Stack tab. The frame before `kernel32.dll` or `kernelbase.dll` is usually a good one to investigate, but it's not always clear, which is why I checked several DLL files.

Comment: +1, some great detective work here. Based on this it seems pretty conclusive that the `SuperHidden` key was a mistake. The OCD in me really wishes they'd actually used that key instead of `ShowSuperHidden`, just for the sake of naming consistency with `Hidden`.

Comment: Very nice +1 and on the other post as well.

Comment: Why Windows 10 shell32.dll shows a different address of Show SuperHidden? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QueSi.png).

Comment: @Biswa Good question! Different compiler/linker versions sometimes lay out the output files differently. Additionally, I think that screenshot is from a 64-bit version, while mine are from 32-bit systems, which will cause addresses and sizes to be different.

Comment: I joined SuperUser to upvote this! You included a number of useful things in addition to SuperHidden: another use of ProcMon, the incredible IDA tool, plus the tips in the linked question. Thank you!